# MLPClassifier in BaggingClassifier

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

Is there any way I can use `partial_fit()` in a `BagginClassifier()` which contains multiple `MLPClassifier()`?
My problem is binary classification, something like this:

```
clf = MLPClassifier()
model = BaggingClassifier(base_estimator=clf)
model.partial_fit(x, y, classes=[0, 1])
```

It keeps me giving this error:

```
AttributeError: 'BaggingClassifier' object has no attribute 'partial_fit'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like it isn't. The [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/0.15/modules/scaling_strategies.html#incremental-learning) of  `sklearn` gave the following list of modules that support `partial_fit`:

```
sklearn.naive_bayes.MultinomialNB
sklearn.naive_bayes.BernoulliNB
sklearn.linear_model.Perceptron
sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier
sklearn.linear_model.PassiveAggressiveClassifier

sklearn.linear_model.SGDRegressor
sklearn.linear_model.PassiveAggressiveRegressor

sklearn.cluster.MiniBatchKMeans

sklearn.decomposition.MiniBatchDictionaryLearning
sklearn.cluster.MiniBatchKMeans
```

Comment: When linking to documentation, it's important to ensure that you don't so so in some outdated version. ALthough the essence of the answer doesn't change, tou link to an old version (0.15); here is the link for the [latest stable version](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/computing.html#incremental-learning) (0.22) which includes some other models indeed

Comment: @desertnaut in your link appears `MLPClassifier` as estimator allowed to use `partial_fit`, but how could I use it if I'm using a `BaggingClassifier` which contains some `MLPClassifier`?

Comment: @Omar I just guess the rationale is similar with the one offered in your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61148798/attributeerror-mlpclassifier-object-has-no-attribute-decision-function) - in case of bagging classifier, both it and the base one  must include the attribute. Not quite sure though, and the docs are not very enlightening.